# How to send value if input not empty in insert batch CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, bulkinsert

Basically I have this which sends the value entered to the database:

```
    $tag = $this->input->post('tags[]');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($tag as $term){
        $data[] = array(
            'post_id'  => $post_id,
            'term_id'  => $term,
            'user_id'  => $this->input->post('user_id'),
            'status'  => 'attached',
            'type'     =>  'tag',
        );

    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $data);
```

but I'm trying to make the user_id "optional" by making the admin enter a X-user as the value or his session user_id in case he decides to leave it empty..

I tried doing this but it still did not work:

```
    $tag = $this->input->post('tags[]');

    $data = array();

    foreach ($tag as $term){
        $data[] = array(
            'post_id'  => $post_id,
            'term_id'  => $term,
            //'user_id'  => $this->input->post('user_id'),
            'status'  => 'attached',
            'type'     =>  'tag',
        );

    }

    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

    if(empty($user_id)){
        $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    } else {
        $data['user_id'] = $user_id;
    }

    $this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $data);
```

As you can see I commented the user_id in the foreach and then I added it in the next block of code which is supposed to check whether or not the imput is empty.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That if statement must be inside that foreach.

```
$tag = $this->input->post('tags[]');
$user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

$data = array();

foreach ($tag as $key => $term){
    $data[$key] = array(
        'post_id'  => $post_id,
        'term_id'  => $term,
        'status'  => 'attached',
        'type'     =>  'tag',
    );

    if(empty($user_id)){
        $data[$key]['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    } else {
        $data[$key]['user_id'] = $user_id;
    }
}

$this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think no need to add more line just do this in on side

```
$data[] = array(
        'post_id'  => $post_id,
        'term_id'  => $term,
        'user_id'  => (!empty($this->input->post('user_id')) ? $this->input->post('user_id') : '',
        'status'  => 'attached',
        'type'     =>  'tag',
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tag = $this->input->post('tags[]');

$data = array();

foreach ($tag as $key => $term){
if(empty($this->input->post('user_id')))
{
$data[$key] = array(
        'post_id'  => $post_id,
        'term_id'  => $term,
        'status'  => 'attached',
        'type'     =>  'tag',
    );

}
else
{
$data[$key] = array(
        'post_id'  => $post_id,
        'term_id'  => $term,
        'user_id'  => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'status'  => 'attached',
        'type'     =>  'tag',
    );

}
}

$this->db->insert_batch('ci_relationship', $data);
```

Hope it works for you.